# jquery validation working in one form and not in the other form

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm having two forms on a same page in a tabbed index as in [jqueryui.com/tabs/#](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default)

I've included the js files:

jquery.validate.js, additional-methods.js, jquery.js

Form in First TAB:

```
<form action="#" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="org" id="org" autocomplete="off">         
  <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
       <td> <label>Name: </label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="head" value="" id="head" class="required"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label></label></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add" onclick="javascript:addForm();" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Form in the second TAB:

```
 <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="orgEdit" id="orgEdit" autocomplete="off">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
       <td><label>Head: </label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="editHead" value="" id="editHead" class="required"  /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><label></label></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update" onclick="javascript:editForm();" /></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </form>
```

The validation part on click the submit buttons of those two forms are as follows,

```
<script>
function addForm() {
    $("#org").validate({
        rules: {
            head: {
                required:true,
                letterswithbasicpunc:true
            },
        },
        messages: { 
            head: {
                required:"&nbsp;Please enter head name.",
                letterswithbasicpunc:"&nbsp;Please enter only characters."
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post("url",$("#org").serialize(),function(data){ 
                if(data != 'E') {
                    alert("Data Inserted Successfully.");
                    location.reload();
                } else
                    alert("Failed.");
            });
        }
    });
}

function editForm() {
    $("#orgEdit").validate({ 
        rules: {
            editHead: {
                required:true,
                letterswithbasicpunc:true
            },
        },
        messages: { 
            editHead: {
                required:"&nbsp;Please enter head name.",
                letterswithbasicpunc:"&nbsp;Please enter only characters."
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { 
            $.post("url",$("#orgEdit").serialize(),function(data){
                if(data != 'E') {
                    alert("Data Inserted Successfully.");
                    location.reload();
                } else
                    alert("Failed.");
            });
        }
    });
}
    </script>
```

The jquery validation is working fine while adding the data but it fails in the edit form.
Please help me on this.

Comment: what do you mean by "fails"? does it never validate correctly? or validation doesn't run at all?

Comment: Validation doesn't run at all, On clicking the update buttion "editForm" function is called after that the page is getting refreshed.

Comment: when the validator is called if the form if the inputs fields are not visible then they will not be validated

Comment: Thanks for your time guys. There seems to be a conflict the js files. Let me try to remove that.

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you please clarify your comment about field visibility and validation not working?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the code as below:

```
<form onsubmit="return editForm(this);" action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="orgEdit" id="orgEdit"      autocomplete="off">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
       <td><label>Head: </label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="editHead" value="" id="editHead" class="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label></label></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update" /></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function editForm(form) {
    $(form).validate({ 
      rules: {
        editHead: {
            required:true,
            letterswithbasicpunc:true
        },
      },
      messages: { 
        editHead: {
            required:"&nbsp;Please enter head name.",
            letterswithbasicpunc:"&nbsp;Please enter only characters."
         },
       },
      submitHandler: function(form) { 
        $.post("url",$("#orgEdit").serialize(),function(data){
            if(data != 'E') {
                alert("Data Inserted Successfully.");
                location.reload();
            } else
                alert("Failed.");
        });
      }
    });
   return $(form).valid();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. There seems to be a conflict the js files.